# Ubuntu 20.04 how to start viber-mtd minimized at tray?

Tags: 20.04, startup-applications, system-tray, minimize, viber

Ubuntu 20.04
installing viber-mtd via Ubuntu Software
and add to "Startup Aplications" for autorun on booting system.

Viber start at open window. **How to start viber-mtd at system tray (minimized)?**

`StartMinimized` parameter does not working

```
/snap/bin/viber-mtd.viber StartMinimized
```

and `-startintray` flag don't work too.

```
/snap/bin/viber-mtd.viber -startintray
```

and can't unmark settings at Viber aplication "Start Viber on system startup"

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `/snap/bin/viber-mtd.viber -min` ?

Comment: @guttermonk flag " -min " started viber by open window too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you can use devilspie to auto-minimize Viber windows whenever they are opened:

First, apt install devilspie, and put the following into `~/.devilspie/viber-minimize.ds`:

```lisp
(if (is (application_name) "Viber <your viber number>")  
    (begin (minimize))
)
```

then simply set devilspie to start at boot, and Viber to start up *after* that. To ensure this you could set this script to run at boot:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
devilspie &
/snap/bin/viber-mtd.viber
```

Note that once you start a Viber instance, un-minimizing it from tray will work as expected, devilspie won't interfere (it only acts on newly-opened windows, not opened-but-minimized ones).

Comment: unfortunately don't work. I installed devilspie, than created ~/.devilspie folder, than created and fill file ~/.devilspie/viber-minimize.ds (sudo chmod 755), than create .sh file (sudo chmod 755) and put to Startup Aplications and it's not work. Viber opens at open window, when startup.

Comment: but, I will change at `~/.devilspie/viber-minimize.ds` application_name (work window_name too) from "Viber" to "Viber <my phone number>" and it will works. And it Work with my skype problem too.

Comment: @discipleartem Thanks, I've edited the answer